# Replacing a line in a textile leaving remains of oldLine

Tags: java, text, methods, replace

I have a textfile, `inventory.txt`, with

```
cats, 10, 15
dogs, 10, 15
```

I want to run a code where I can input `cats` as `replacee` and `turtles, 5, 5` as the `replacer`, giving me,

```
turtles, 5, 5
dogs, 10, 15
```

however, when I do this, everything after the first comma remains in addition to my `replacer`. I can replace `cats` with JUST `turtles` with no `5, 5`, giving me

```
turtles, 10, 15
dogs, 10, 15
```

but when I try adding the `5, 5` after the first comma remains, output below.

**Code**

```
public void modifyItems() throws IOException {

        File file = new File("src/inventory.txt");
        String line = "";
        String oldLine = "";
        String replacee;
        String replacer;

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            oldLine += line + System.lineSeparator();

        }
        System.out.println(oldLine);
        reader.close();

        System.out.println("enter the item you want to edit");
        replacee = scan.next();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("enter the updated information");
        replacer = scan.nextLine();
        String newLine = oldLine.replaceAll(replacee, replacer);

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        writer.write(newLine);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

**Output**

```
cats, 10, 15
dogs, 10, 15

enter the item you want to edit
cats
enter the updated information
turtles, 5, 5
```

**Textfile output**

```
turtles, 5, 5, 10, 15
dogs, 10, 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String` `replaceAll` method does what you've seen in your code.  It replaces the text you input with the inventory string you input.

The method you want to use is the `String` `startsWith` method.

You need to keep an array of lines read, so you can find the correct line to replace.

```
public void modifyItems() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("src/inventory.txt");

    // Replace 100 with a large enough number to hold
    // the whole file.
    String[] oldLine = new String[100];

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(file));
    int count = 0;
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        oldLine[count] = line + System.lineSeparator();
        System.out.println(line);
        count++;
    }
    reader.close();

    System.out.println("enter the item you want to edit");
    String replacee = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter the updated information");
    String replacer = scan.nextLine();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(file));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (oldLine[i].startsWith(replacee)) {
            writer.write(replacer);
        } else {
            writer.write(oldLine[i]);
        }
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```